# Error Creating Select List in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, bokeh

I am trying to create a Select widget driven bar graph and am struggling on the very first piece of purely implementing the Select widget.

I currently have a list of companies that I generate with the following:

```
tech_firms = list(sorted(tech_valid['Company Name'].unique()))
```

Which as far as I know is simply a list.  When I debug in Jupyter I get what looks like a list output (with a scroll bar)

**Not Working:**
The below does not work and I receive the error: **expected an element of either List(Either(String, Tuple(Either(Int, String),String))) or Dict(String, List(Either(String, Tuple(Either(Int,String)(,String)))), got Select(description='Tech Firms', options= ....)** and the list of all the names within `tech_firms`

```
#drop down population
select = Select(title="Tech Firms", value="Apple", options=tech_firms)
show(widgetbox(select))
```

If I try the following it works, but it's not at all an effective solution given that I have many names in the list and as the dataset changes and evolves it's quite plausible new companies could appear and others could disappear.  What am I missing?

**Working:**

```
#drop down population
select = Select(title='Tech Firms', value='Apple', options=['Apple', 'Google', 'DeepMind', 'Amazon'])
show(widgetbox(select))
```

Showing some values that are in `tech_firms` as requested:
(I pulled this from the exception so that it shows as is during the throw):

```
got Select(description='Tech Firms', options=('Apple', 'Amazon', 'DeepMind', 'Google', 'Tesla, Inc.', 'Arlington Corp.', 'YouTube')
```

Comment: can you show some values that are in `tech_firms` ?

Comment: @zimdero added to the above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was in that I was unnecessarily designating the dataframe column as a list.  Apparently, for some reason, this does not work.

My solution was to create a new var without the list cast by the following `tech_firms_list = tech_firms['Company Name'].unique()`

Upon creation of the select drop down I sorted the list when processing the `options` param via the following:

```
select = Select(title="Tech Firms", value="Amazon Inc.", options=sorted(tech_firms_list))
```

Apparently the list cast caused some issues as an argument.  If anyone knows exactly why that would happen please let me know I would like to have a firm understanding of these mechanics.

Comment: I realize this was a really long time ago, but did you ever decipher this error?

Comment: For the record, the .unique() method described above didn't work for me.  However, it did work when I converted the data in the column from floats to strings. (i.e. `tech_firms['Company Name'].astype(str).unique()`)

Comment: @alofgran Unfortunately not.  What I posted above worked for me, but i'm not certain as to why the error occurred.  There is nothing obvious to me that would incite that exception.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work when you have `na` in your unique list. So drop `na` before you call `unique()`.

```py
tech_valid.dropna()
tech_valid['Company Name'].unique().tolist()
```